# Jena version supported by oracle 11g (11.2.0.3) spatial

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, spatial, jena

Where can I find out what is the latest jena version supported by oracle 11g (11.2.0.3)  spatial?

I am currently using jena 2.6.4, and the reason I'm asking is that
some large queries fails with this jena, and one of my friend suggested using the latest version of jena.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because any answer will not be correct for long. The best place to find this information is the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11828/sem_jena.htm, which will be kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ben's comment, while this will change with time, this piece of information can be found in the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11828/sem_jena.htm, which will be kept up to date.